# Why Is My Android ListView singleChoice Mode Not Working?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm building my app with the example from
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter

Originally when a listview item is clicked it will redirect to a single item view but i have comment that part of code so that when item is clicked nothing happens. The code starts from
// Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class

Then in listview_main.xml i have modified the listview xml as

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="#003366" />
```

I would expect that when i click an item it will be highlight and stay highlighted but it's not happening.

Comment: Could you please attach your code

Comment: My code is exactly the same as shown in the tutorial except that i commented the part to Listen for ListView Item Click where it'll start a new activity when a listview item is clicked.